# why is the display modifier button in blender 2.8 purple?

Tags: modifiers, 3d-view

anyone know why this button is now purple ? Just happened and I do not know from whence the maroon did come.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Purple indicates a driver.**

For the most part, (*unless you are using some whaky theme*) purple in a field indicates a driver has been added.

To remove, right click over field and choose delete driver. (adding driver is most likely how you got there in the first place)

[image]

*Oops added driver to diff prop from Q, same deal though*

**Note**

In Q screenshot you have the apply all and viewport vis buttons *etc* above modifiers, which I assume is from an addon.  Possibly this is using a driver on the modifier visibility switch

Comment: that did it. thanks. don't even know what a driver is.